# Could I make Stack use my patched Cabal library?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Does anyone know if there exists an easy way to make [Stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack) use specific patched version of Cabal library from my GitHub repository? I'm very pleased with how can I use forked versions of other packages by just putting them into `packages:` section of `stack.yaml`, but that doesn't seem to work with Cabal.

What I wanted is some way to specify git repository URL and revision in `stack.yaml` and have Cabal library built from that source, not from Hackage or whatever upstream repository. Could this be done?

Answer (score 3):

Stack will use the newest version of the Cabal library in your global database, so installing it there (such as by using the Setup.hs script directly) should work.